# How to open data-url on modal clicking by anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Actually it's opening after second click but I want to open it first click I guess it can be possible with jquery event. so why I added `data-target` and data-toggle with jquery ? because if my `data-title` is `blank` I will open my link on new tab but if my `data-title` is pop than I wil open it with bootstrap modal that's why I'm trying to add with jquery.

[please click to see on codepen](https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/EmVvJj)

```js
$(document).on("click", "a[data-title]", function() {

  var target = $(this).data("title");

  var targetLink = $(this).attr("href");
  if (target == "pop") {
    $(this).attr({
      'data-target': '#carouselModal',
      'data-toggle': 'modal',
    });
    return false;
  } else if (target == "blank") {
    window.open(targetLink, '_blank');
    return false;
  } else {

  }

});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">


  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-8-content" data-title="pop"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-5-us"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315" data-title="blank"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-2-posts" data-title="pop"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="carouselModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Kapat</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- carousel modal-->

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If it's opening after second click, propably there is something undefined at first time.

Comment: I don't know maybe

Comment: Try opening directly with code instead of setting the attributes.

Comment: it work's than but I have to use with attribute because if my value of attribute is pop than open it with modal or if blank than open with new tab

Comment: It will obviously work on second click, because your `function` is only adding `attrs` which will bind `modal` function, and then on second click it will run bootstraps predefined function.

Comment: as I expected than how can I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is working the way it supposed to work, because your function is only adding `attrs` which will bind `modal()`, and then on second click it will run bootstraps predefined function.

The better way is to run `modal()` at the end of your function,

Adding `$('#carouselModal').modal('show');` at end of the if condition will work.

```js
$(document).on("click", "a[data-title]", function() {

  var target = $(this).data("title");

  var targetLink = $(this).attr("href");
  if (target == "pop") {
    $(this).attr({
      'data-target': '#carouselModal',
      'data-toggle': 'modal',
    });
    $('#carouselModal .modal-body').html('<a href='+targetLink+'>'+targetLink+'</a>');
    $('#carouselModal').modal('show');
    return false;
  } else if (target == "blank") {
    window.open(targetLink, '_blank');
    return false;
  } else {

  }

});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">


  <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-8-content" data-title="pop"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=114"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-5-us"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=315" data-title="blank"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.anitur.com.tr/popup/test-2-posts" data-title="pop"><img src="https://unsplash.it/1400/600?image=622"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="carouselModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Kapat</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- carousel modal-->

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ok so that how can I load on modal-body ? example it's work but hrefis not loading

Comment: I don't need to print href I just load href

Comment: Load?, where? can you elaborate more? Do you want to load `href`'s content in modal box?

Comment: for example if you gonna click first slide you will see https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/EmVvJj

Comment: oouw on debug mode it has been open as content not link I mean I get content of href

Comment: In that case you need to use Iframe. [see this demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/2rwg9Ljf/)

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2rwg9Ljf/1/ actually it possible with this thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the attributes but the updated code will work on `click`

#### Example

```
$(this).attr('data-target', 'newModelID'); // and whatever
```

`click` event should be triggered in order to see changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should dispatch click event after assign new data attribute:

```
 if(target=="pop" && $(this).data('target') == undefined) {
    $(this).attr({
        'data-target':'#carouselModal',
        'data-toggle':'modal',
    });

    $(this).click();

    return false;
}
```

`$(this).data('target') == undefined` needs to prevent eternal loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works,

```
var target = $(this).data("title");

if(target=="pop") {

    $(this).attr({
        'data-target':'#carouselModal',
        'data-toggle':'modal',
    });

    $('#carouselModal').modal('show');

    return;

}else if(target=="blank"){

  window.open(targetLink,'_blank');

    return;

} else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your script to this.

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-title]", function() {
 var target = $(this).data("title");
 var targetLink = $(this).attr("href");

 if (target == "pop") 
 {
    $(".modal-body").load(targetLink);
    $('#carouselModal').modal('toggle');
    return false;
 } 
 else if (target == "blank")
 {
  window.open(targetLink, '_blank');
  return false;
 }

});
```